# Avoid uppercase input with jQuery Validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, jquery-validate

I'm making a classifieds ads website where users submit ads through a form (like Craigslist).  Many users write the title or description of their ads in UPPERCASE to get more attention, but I dont want to affect the overall appearance of the website.

I would like to stop this, but still allow the use of acronyms of less than three uppercase letters in a row (for example allow 'Located in the USA' but not 'LOOK, GREAT OFFER')

I'm a complete newbie with Validate and RegEx (just one weekend) so I need your help experts.

I'm using this method:

```
$.validator.addMethod("noCaps", function(value, element) {
   return this.optional(element) || /[A-Z]{4}/.test(value); 
}, "You are not permitted to input more than three uppercase letters in a row!");
```

But I'm getting the complete opposite result. How could I negate this RegEx to achieve the desired rule?

If somebody has a better idea of how to do it, is also welcome!

Thanks!!!

[See/Edit Example Code](http://jsbin.com/uxeqi4/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add a negation (`!`) in front of it, like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("noCaps", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || !/[A-Z]{4}/.test(value); 
}, "You are not permitted to input more than three uppercase letters in a row!");
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/uBJyz/).

Comment: @swordf1zh - welcome, and welcome to SO! :) Be sure to either accept answers, or let the answerer know what the issue is :)